# Springboot - List down all dependencies and it version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I would like to listdown the dependencies that been use.

I tried to code this way which this method will be called from my main @SpringBootApplication

```
SpringApplication.run(MiddlewareApplication.class, args);
ListJarsAndVersions.main(args);
```

The code is:

```
package com.my.middleware.utils;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.maven.model.Dependency;
import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.Parent;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ListJarsAndVersions {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListJarsAndVersions.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LOG.info("Starting....");
            listPOMsParent();
            listPOMsDependencies();

        } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void listPOMsParent() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("pom.xml")) { // Adjust the path
            model = reader.read(fileReader);
        }

        Parent parent = model.getParent();
        while (parent != null) {
            LOG.debug("Parent POM:");
            LOG.debug("  Group ID: " + parent.getGroupId());
            LOG.debug("  Artifact ID: " + parent.getArtifactId());
            LOG.debug("  Version: " + parent.getVersion());

            // Move to the next parent POM
            String parentPomPath = parent.getRelativePath();
            if (parentPomPath == null || parentPomPath.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            try (FileReader parentFileReader = new FileReader(parentPomPath)) {
                Model parentModel = reader.read(parentFileReader);
                parent = parentModel.getParent();
            }
        }

        if (model.getDependencyManagement() != null) {
            LOG.debug("|Group ID |Artifact ID |Version");
            model.getDependencyManagement().getDependencies().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Dependency::getGroupId).thenComparing(Dependency::getArtifactId))
            .forEach(dependency -> {
                LOG.debug("| {} | {} | {}", dependency.getGroupId(),dependency.getArtifactId(), dependency.getVersion());
            });
        }

    }

    private static void listPOMsDependencies() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("pom.xml")) { // Adjust the path
            model = reader.read(fileReader);
        }
        List<Dependency> dependencies = model.getDependencies();
        LOG.debug("List of Maven Dependencies:");
        for (Dependency dependency : dependencies) {
            LOG.debug(
                    "  " + dependency.getGroupId() + ":" + dependency.getArtifactId() + ":" + dependency.getVersion());
        }
    }
}
```

So with this, I getting the output as below

```
2023-10-10T10:24:15.885+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          : Parent POM:
2023-10-10T10:24:15.886+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   Group ID: org.springframework.boot
2023-10-10T10:24:15.886+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   Artifact ID: spring-boot-starter-parent
2023-10-10T10:24:15.886+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   Version: 3.1.4
2023-10-10T10:24:15.888+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          : List of Maven Dependencies:
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.postgresql:postgresql:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.projectlombok:lombok:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:null
2023-10-10T10:24:15.889+08:00 DEBUG 19920 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.utils.ListJarsAndVersions          :   org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.8.3
```

some of it showing null (example `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:null` because the `POM` file don't have the version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>Middleware</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Middleware</name>
    <description>Code</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I think it controlled by the parent which is `spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.4`

I can get expected output using `mvn dependency:tree` but how I can pull data and get the version of dependencies that is not define inside POM file using java code ?

Answer (score 3):

Run this command from terminal/command line in your project folder:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This will list versions of all libraries in use for your project.

Comment: I looking for the same output but using java code

Comment: Have you taken a look at Maven Dependency repo on how they are doing it? https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin